# Saving Message object from JavaMail to Filesystem

Tags: java, file, object, serialization, jakarta-mail

The message class is not serializable therefore you can't store its object in a file. I've tried to extract the important parts of it in order to call the constructor but it depends on other classes which are not serializable. In there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [mbox local store provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#localprovs).  Otherwise you can use [javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(OutputStream)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) to store a message to the file system and [javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage(Session, InputStream)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage-javax.mail.Session-java.io.InputStream-) to create a message from the file system.